# Kamailio and sipML5 and unable to get a connection

Tags: kamailio, sipml5

I have attempted using sipML5 instead of tryit jsip but I have not been able to figure out the configuration. I am having kamailio listen on port 15000 so I changed my sipML5 to wss://21.1.1.32:15000. I see the request coming through to kamalio but I just see a disconnected message from sipML5. I have tried many configurations but just can't get a connection.  Any ideas?

Also, does any know where to look for documentation on learning the flow of a kamalio configuration file.  I have seen many examples and people seem to place there different routes and functions all over the place.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you said your kamailio is listening on port 15000 but is it `UDP, TCP,TLS, WS or WSS`

- In order to connect a `webSocket client` like `SIPml5` to SIP server like `Kamailio` you must connect it with the `WS` port of the server where server listen and interprets `webSocket clients`, your Websocket client will not listen to the UDP/TCP/TLS port.
- Also you need to configure your `kamailio` to handle  `webSocket Connections`, you can read how to configure websocket here its quite simple : https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/devel/modules/websocket.html
- `If you compiled your kamailio from sources rather than apt-get install method` In case above point didn't helped , i would recall that your kamailio sources comes bundled with some  `Example CFGs` and you can look for `websocket.cfg` into it.